# Django ORM Table Relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have models defined like so:

```
class Games(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Votes(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Games)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And i'm doing the following in my view:

```
wanted = Games.objects.filter(owned=0)
for game in wanted:
    game.vote = Votes.objects.all().filter(game_id=game.id).count()
wanted = sorted(wanted, key=attrgetter('vote'), reverse=True)
```

It works fine but is there a more Django way of doing this?

Comment: Try this: `wanted = Games.objects.filter(owned=0).annotate(vote_count=Count('votes'))).order_by('-vote_count')` (Untested. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Games.objects.filter(owned=0).annotate(vote=Count('votes')).order_by('-vote')
```

see [Django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) for more information

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for including the doc as well. Exactly the type of answer i was looking for.